# How to get Grunt UnCss to compile based on the homepage

Tags: css, gruntjs, uncss

I am trying to get UnCss to produce a cut down version of my master CSS file, for now I only want to get this working on the homepage as a test.

I am using the following code:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      stylesheets  : ['localhost/assets/css/master-2014.css'],
      urls         : ['localhost/en-gb/']
    },
    files: {
      'css/app.clean.css': ['localhost/en-gb/']
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is read `master-2014.css` from my local server (and eventually a remote url e.g. google.com), then look at the page that I have got the stylesheet from (my homepage `localhost`) and determine which style is needed. I finally want to then produce this into `app.clean.css`.

Currently I cannot get this to work for the life of me I have tried other variations like:

```
    files: {
      'css/app.clean.css': ['**/*.Master', '**/*.ascx']
    }
```

This does not work.

I have also seen people try something like this:

```
    files: {
      'css/app.clean.css': ['index.html']
    }
```

Where `index.html` is a blank html file. This is the only one that succeeds but it just creates me a css file which only contains css for `html` and `body`. The rest all throw the following error:

```
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
Warning: Destination (css/app.clean.css) not written because src files were empty. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

All other examples that I can find are for WordPress which is PHP and this is a .Net site.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Nope, I was not able to solve this issue unfortunately. Due to time restrictions I had to give up on this option. If you have a solution that would be fantastic.